# Adiabatic invariance regime

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, error-analysis, adiabatic

Consider a system executing a finite motion, described by its hamiltonian $H$ and characterized by some parameter $\lambda(t)$ being varied over time.

Reading Landau & Lifshitz (Mechanics, paragraph 49), I am having trouble understanding what does it mean for $T\frac{d\lambda}{dt}$ to be *much smaller* than $\lambda$ (where $T$ is the period of motion) in order to consider $\lambda$ as adiabatically varying. In particular I can't figure out why imposing this condition is a valid reason to take the $\frac{d\lambda}{dt}$ factor out while averaging the quantity:
$$\frac{dH}{dt}=\frac{d\lambda}{dt}\frac{\partial H}{\partial \lambda}\tag{49.2}$$
over a period to get $$\overline{\frac{dH}{dt}}=\frac{d\lambda}{dt}\overline{\frac{\partial H}{\partial \lambda}}\tag{49.3}$$ as L&L do.
In other words: in order for us to neglect the variation of $\lambda$ over a period, shouldn't it be that this variation ($T\frac{d\lambda}{dt}$) were much smaller than our experimental uncertainty, rather than $\lambda$ itself?